# How to stop thumbnail generation from some images and different size thumbnail generate

Tags: images, uploads, post-thumbnails, thumbnails

I have 4 Post Type, and each Post Type has images with different size. Is it possible to choose not to create thumbnail images when uploading an image or to create specific images size for each post type?
example: 1 post type: not need to thumbnail generation And only the original uploaded site is required.  2 post type: Requires 3 different sizes. 3 post type: Requires 2 different sizes. and...